# Часть значений в Settings не сохраняется как нужно

Tags: c#

У меня есть простенькая прога которая сохраняет некие 2 интовые значения в Settings.Settings апликухи.

LoadResults() вызывается на старте программы.

```
private void LoadResults()
{
    nUdVgadano.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.Vgadano;
    nUdNeVgadano.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.NotVgadano;
}

private void SaveResults(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Vgadano = (int)nUdVgadano.Value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.NotVgadano = (int)nUdNeVgadano.Value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    //Added Just for tests
    LoadResults();
}
```

Что странно - первое значение сохраняется, а вот второе -- отказывается и ВСЕГДА после перезапуска апликухи подгружается со значением 0.

Отдельно забавным фактом является то, что если добавить в SaveResults() в конец вызов LoadResults(); -- то значение второго сеттинга не обнуляется.

То есть по какой-то причине второй сеттинг обнуляется только после перезапуска всей апликухи. А .Save(); вызывается только из одного места во всей программе.

Пробовал:

- Clean-нить солюшн
- построчно дебажить.
- второй сеттинг удалить и создать еще один вместо него с другим именем.
- Пробовал компилить в релиз и запускать вручную

поведение ровно то же самое. Ничего не помогло.

По логике:

Если бы я допустил ошибку где-то, то оно бы не сохраняло оба значения... Но почему с идентичным кодом оно сохраняет одно значение, но игнорирует второе? =(

Почему обнуляется только при перезапуске но без перезапуска оно нормально сохраняет значения?

Comment: Одинакова ли область действия (scope) у настроек? Может, попробуете создать минимальный пример: удалить из проекта буквально все, кроме `Settings.Default.NotVgadano = 1; Settings.Default.Save();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и ожидалось, оказалось что я просто тупой :)

Дело было в том, что на SaveResults висел как ивент на изменении NumericUpDown.Value.

То есть если я в LoadResults подгружал новое значение изменяя сам NumericUpDown.Value то вызывался снова метод SaveResults который затирал второе значение нулем.